# Recognizing text as Simplified vs. Traditional Chinese

Tags: php, unicode, cjk, language-detection

Given a block of text that's known to be Chinese and encoded in UTF-8, is there a way to determine if it's Simplified or Traditional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but I'd try using iconv to see if it will translate between the charsets correctly, comparing the results from the same conversion with //TRANSLIT and //IGNORE. If the two results match, then the charset conversion hasn't encountered any characters that fail to translate, so you should have a match.

```
$test1 = iconv("UTF-8", "big5//TRANSLIT", $text);
$test2 = iconv("UTF-8", "big5//IGNORE", $text);
if ($test1 == $test2) {
   echo 'traditional';
} else {
   $test3 = iconv("UTF-8", "gb2312//TRANSLIT", $text);
   $test4 = iconv("UTF-8", "gb2312//IGNORE", $text);
   if ($test3 == $test4) {
      echo 'simplified';
   } else {
      echo 'Failed to match either traditional or simplified';
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! It seems to definitely be working, although a lot of text is coming back as "neither" (example: "聲音 鳥 樹葉 話 説話 細 又 輕 蝴蝶 請 只有 和 得 聼得到 蜜蜂"). Any ideas? I also had to do `@iconv` for the 2 `TRANSLIT` calls to suppress errors.

Comment: You've got some z-variant characters in there that aren't in basic GB-2312, but they are in GB-18030. Try `'gb18030'` instead of `'gb2312'`. Or if your input is Windows-oriented you may prefer `'cp936'` (and `'cp950'` instead of `'big5'`).

Comment: I swapped in `gb18030` and all of my test data was recognized. (Cannot be sure of the accuracy though).  Thanks!

Comment: GB18030 is a Unicode Transformation Format, i.e. GB18030 will match every single character inside Unicode, traditional, archaic or simplified (and including, say Korean and Arabic).  The text quoted is clearly Traditional Chinese but 聼 is not included inside Big5 despite it being a Traditional Chinese character.

Answer (score 2):

Since `big5` and `gb2312` omit quite a few commonly used variants that are present in Unicode, the code rely on exact match between the `translit` and `ignore` modes would fail in quite a lot of normal use cases: it would fail to identify `説話` as Traditional Chinese despite `説` being a common variant in Hong Kong for `說` which is used in `big5`.

A simple fix is to do it in a fuzzy way:

```
$test1 = iconv("UTF-8", "big5//IGNORE", $text);
$test2 = iconv("UTF-8", "gb2312//IGNORE", $text);
$len1 = mb_strlen($test1);
$len2 = mb_strlen($test2);
$len0 = mb_strlen($text) * 0.8; // threshold
if ($len1 > $len2 && $len1 > $len0) {
    return 'Likely Traditional';
}
if ($len2 > $len1 && $len2 > $len0) {
    return 'Likely Simplified';
}
return 'Could not identify';
```