# Php - regular expression to check if the string has chinese chars

Tags: php, regex, string, cjk

I have the string `$str` and I want to check if it`s content has Chinese chars or not (true/false)

```
$str = "赕就可消垻,只有当所有方块都被消垻时才可以过关";
```

can you please help me?

Thanks!
Adrian

Comment: What character set is this in? UTF-8 or one of the local ones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect chinese (multibyte) character in the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550950/detect-chinese-multibyte-character-in-the-string)

Comment: @Pekka I tried that and it`s not working for me

Comment: Check if the text simply contains some Chinese characters (with other non-Chinese characters)? or is comprised entirely of Chinese characters?

Comment: @Mark Baker the string can be Chinese with English for example

Comment: In that case, use mario's solution, and don't forget to accept his answer

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could use a unicode character class http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

```
preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $utf8_str);
```

This just checks for the presence of at least one chinese character. You might want to expand on this if you want to match the complete string.

Comment: Great answer.  Didn't know you could identify unicode via regex!

Comment: @Peter: It's a bit recent. Depends on the version, but a Unicode-compatible `PCRE_VERSION` should be bundled since PHP4.

Comment: IIRC, this also depends on the PCRE library on the server having Unicode handling enabled. But it should be present on most modern servers.

Comment: @Pekka: Ah nice, instant upgrade!, it's indeed a shared library. (Probably depends on the build parameters. PHP 5.3.3 still bundles an outdated libpcre version 7.8 from 2008.)

Comment: This answer is terrific. Chapeau.

Comment: Tried it with this string and it doesn't catch it: 人中之龍,Yakuza 3,SEGA,PS4,重製版,《人中之龍 3》PS4 重製版 釋出全新預告及遊戲截圖,影音相關,Game LIFE 遊戲情報    At least some of these characters appear to be Chinese according to the online dictionaries

Answer (score 3):

`@mario` answer is right!

For Chinese chars use this regex: `/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+/u`

And Don't forget the `u` modifier!!!

About `u` modifier [reference](http://php.net/manual/zh/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

TKS to mario

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match("/^\p{Han}{2,10}+$/u", $str);
```

Use **/^\p{Han}{2,10}+$/u** regex which allows Chinese character only.

1. It allows chinese character only &
2. It allows Minimum 2 character &
3. It allows maximum 10 character

You can change minimum and maximum character by changing {2,10} as per your need.

**\p** & **/u** are very important to add please don't avoid to add it.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083038/recognizing-text-as-simplified-vs-traditional-chinese/) to a previous question on identifying simplified or traditional Chinese might give you some ideas... you don't actually specify which you mean, and I don't know Chinese well enough to recognise the difference

Comment: Hey, this is a great idea and has less dependencies than an Unicode Regex. +1

Comment: @Pekka - I have to confess, I was surprised it actually worked (even if it did need a bit of help from bobince with the actual charsets).... just one of those theories that I'd never had a chance to try in practise.