# Detect non-alphabetic language string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, utf-8

I have a similar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php)

However, I have a less strict requirement.

All I need is to detect if the input string contains any non alphabetic string.

If it does contain non-alphabetic string, then I will select a different font file.

if it contains ONLY alphabetic string, then I will select a font file like AmericanTypeWriter.

**By alphabetic string, that would include all kinds of possible symbols such as commas, punctuations, etc.**

It is hard to define alphabetic string.

Let me define what is an example of non-alphabetic string.

这是中文

And assuming utf-8 format for the string.

**Another way to define: anything that does not fall under non-European language character, is automatically assumed to be alphabetic string.**

I need to do this detection in php by the way.

Comment: Is _"alphabetic"_ more than what's included in the `[:alpha:]` regex class?

Comment: where is this :alpha regex class?

Comment: @Joey: the POSIX regex functions (ereg*) are, but I don't believe the POSIX character classes are; they are fully supported in PCRE (preg*) as well.

Comment: @Kimsia: http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better answer. Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923410/80353

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');

function isThisChineseText($text) {
    return preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ctype_alnum(string)`. Documentation [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php). This function takes in a string and returns a `bool` that tells you whether the string contains other characters or not.

You could also use a more complex regex which will work and check for spaces. The following should work.

`preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/u", $string) == 1` will do the trick.

Comment: oh that does not work well, because i may have spaces. this function only tests for alphanumeric not including spaces

Comment: Sorry for not stating it clearly. Usual punctuation such as commas and exclamation marks fall under the AmericanTypeWriter font so alphabetic string would include it as well.

Comment: Based on your use of regex, all i need to do is add in the punctuation symbols. Am I right? preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9,\.\-_! ]*$", $string) == 1

Comment: Yes, please acccept answer if it helped you

Comment: I have up voted the answer. I will probably edit the answer a bit and accept it AFTER i tried this out in the php app. in the meantime, thank you @secretformula

Comment: Works. Thanks. Got another question about PHP here http://stackoverflow.com/q/11101544/80353