# detecting chinese characters in php string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to detect chinese characters in a string I have in PHP, currently I am trying to do this:

```
$bio = '全部都好有用架 無用的我都一早打入冷宮唔見哂(… 有意/想睇圖都歡迎留whatsapp or line: chibimasakishop 可綠線/將軍澳線交收';
    if (preg_match('/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+.*\-/u', $bio) === 1) {
        var_dump('contains a chinese character');
    }
```

why isn't this working?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923319/php-check-if-the-string-has-chinese-chars

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
if(preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $bio))
{
  var_dump('contains a chinese character');
}
```

**Reference** : [Php check if the string has Chinese chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923319/php-check-if-the-string-has-chinese-chars)

Answer (score 5):

in your case i think you have "\-" extra, i think

```
/[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+.*/u
```

should work

Comment: This won't detect Chinese characters accurately. Some characters are treated non-Chinese characters.