# How to detect Chinese character with punctuation in regex?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, unicode

I have noticed that there are question asked on how to detect Chinese character with regex. These are some question I read on stackoverflow:

[Php check if the string has Chinese chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923319/php-check-if-the-string-has-chinese-chars)

[detecting chinese characters in php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904118/detecting-chinese-characters-in-php-string)

And some article outside stackoverflow:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html - unicode script

Basically they suggest using either `\p{Han}+` or `[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+.*` to detect Chinese character. Is there a way to detect Chinese punctuation mark as well?

Some example (but not all) of Chinese punctuation mark:
：？。，《》「」『』－（）【】

Comment: are you looking for a PHP solution?

Comment: I thought only regex would be enough..... but if it is necessary to do that in code (an make sure it is not hard coding every punctuation mark for checking), php solution would be fine too.

Comment: It might be not so precise, but probably in such cases, you may match punctuation but ASCII punctuation, [`'~(?![[:ascii:]])\p{P}~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/Mo0l7v/1) or `~(?![[:ascii:]])[[:punct:]]~u`.

Comment: @cytsunny the answer would depend on the regex flavor used, so please specify what flavor(s) you have in mind.

Comment: @cytsunny  - Can I link to the answer you selected as the definition of Chinese punctuation? What are they btw ?

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest informing yourself by taking a look at [Zhon](http://zhon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#), a Python library that provides constants commonly used in Chinese text processing.

Luckily, [hanzi.py](https://github.com/tsroten/zhon/blob/develop/zhon/hanzi.py) contains a definition of a regex that should pretty much suit your needs:

```
#: A regular expression pattern for a Chinese sentence. A sentence is defined
#: as a series of characters and non-stop punctuation marks followed by a stop
#: and zero or more container-closing punctuation marks (e.g. apostrophe or brackets).

sent = sentence = '[{characters}{radicals}{non_stops}]*{sentence_end}'.format(
    characters=characters, radicals=radicals, non_stops=non_stops,
    sentence_end=_sentence_end)
```

The definition above results in the following regex<sup>*</sup>:

```
[〇一-鿿㐀-䶿豈-﫿----⼀-⿕⺀-⻳＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－／：；＜＝＞＠［＼］＾＿｀｛｜｝～｟｠｢｣､　、〃〈〉《》「」『』【】〔〕〖〗〘〙〚〛〜〝〞〟〰〾〿–—‘’‛“”„‟…‧﹏﹑﹔·]*[！？｡。][」﹂”』’》）］｝〕〗〙〛〉】]*
```

[Code Example](https://ideone.com/ejCbIA):

```
preg_match_all('/[〇一-鿿㐀-䶿豈-﫿----⼀-⿕⺀-⻳＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－／：；＜＝＞＠［＼］＾＿｀｛｜｝～｟｠｢｣､　、〃〈〉《》「」『』【】〔〕〖〗〘〙〚〛〜〝〞〟〰〾〿–—‘’‛“”„‟…‧﹏﹑﹔·]*[！？｡。][」﹂”』’》）］｝〕〗〙〛〉】]*/', "我的中文不好。我是意大利人。你知道吗？", $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

If you prefer using Character code ranges for pertinent CJK ideograph Unicode blocks reference the Python source I have [linked](https://github.com/tsroten/zhon/blob/develop/zhon/hanzi.py) or get it from the Javascript sample below:

```js
const regex = /[\u3007u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DBF\uF900-\uFAFF\u20000-\u2A6DF\u2A700-\u2B73F\u2B740-\u2B81F\u0002F800-\u2FA1F\u2F00-\u2FD5\u2E80-\u2EF3\uFF02\uFF03\uFF04\uFF05\uFF06\uFF07\uFF08\uFF09\uFF0A\uFF0B\uFF0C\uFF0D\uFF0F\uFF1A\uFF1B\uFF1C\uFF1D\uFF1E\uFF20\uFF3B\uFF3C\uFF3D\uFF3E\uFF3F\uFF40\uFF5B\uFF5C\uFF5D\uFF5E\uFF5F\uFF60\uFF62\uFF63\uFF64\u3000\u3001\u3003\u3008\u3009\u300A\u300B\u300C\u300D\u300E\u300F\u3010\u3011\u3014\u3015\u3016\u3017\u3018\u3019\u301A\u301B\u301C\u301D\u301E\u301F\u3030\u303E\u303F\u2013\u2014\u2018\u2019\u201B\u201C\u201D\u201E\u201F\u2026\u2027\uFE4F\uFE51\uFE54\u00B7]*[\uFF01\uFF1F\uFF61\u3002][」﹂”』’》）］｝〕〗〙〛〉】]*/gm;
const str = `我的中文不好。我是意大利人。你知道吗？`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

PS: I also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109011/javascript-unicode-string-chinese-character-but-no-punctuation/21113538) helpful.

Answer (score 5):

`[\u4e00-\u9fa5]` works for me in VSCode, the other suggested solutions don't. I stumbled on the solution here, which is a online regex interpreter: http://tool.chinaz.com/regex/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to detect Chinese punctuation mark as well?

This is a basic Unicode property regex to get just the punctuation.
It says get all `\p{Han}` script characters, only if they are in the CJK block
for symbols and punctuation.

This effectively filters to Han symbols and punctuation.

As of Unicode 10, this turns out to be these 15 characters:  `々〇〡〢〣〤〥〦〧〨〩〸〹〺〻`

`\p{Han}(?<=\p{Block=CJK_Symbols_And_Punctuation})`

If the engine you're using doesn't support *properties* or doesn't support the
block symbols, you can use a class range of the resulting 15 chars.
which is one of these

`[\x{3005}\x{3007}\x{3021}-\x{3029}\x{3038}-\x{303B}]`
`[\u3005\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303B]`

Source: http://www.regexformat.com UCD Interface.