# Detect if a string contains any punctuation or accentued characters in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, punctuation

I've been looking on internet without finding answers to my problem.
I want that the user enter a login to create his account, but I need to check if there is any punctuation or accentued characters in the login name.
To sum up I only want this kind of characters:
[0-9] or [a-z] or [A-Z] or any asian characters **except** asian punctuations.

What I've been thinking was to do a loop on my string and to look if the actual character is equal to a pronunciation or accentued characters but there are so many punctuations and accentued characters that it would take me a long time to write them all. And the fact is I don't know all the punctuations characters used in the asian writing system.

Do you have any idea about what should I do ? **Thank you !**

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923319/php-check-if-the-string-has-chinese-chars.

Answer (score 0):

You meant, you want to allow only alphanumeric characters? If so, use regular expression. See sample code below.

```
if( preg_match('/^[a-z0-9.,!?:;"-_\']+$/i', $str)){ // Remove unwanted chars if you don't need to include all 
    echo 'Success';
}else{
    echo 'Error!';
}
```

See this documentation for more details. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php http://www.phpforkids.com/php/php-functions-regular-expressions.php

Comment: This won't meet the `any asian characters except asian punctuations` requirement.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Edited my reply.

Comment: This won't match asian characters still and `"-_` is a range. I'm also not sure what asian punctuation looks like but presume it could be different.