# Why \P{C} in PHP preg_match_all() does not match Chinese characters?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

For [this PHP page](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) I know that `\P{C}` matches all non-invisible control characters. And I try the pattern `[\P{C}]*` in this [regex test site](https://regex101.com/), it does match the Chinese characters.

In my PHP 5.6.30 hosted on Apache

```
preg_match_all('#([\P{C}]*)#', '中文', $t_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($t_matches);
```

does not match the Chinese characters correctly. But the following code does:

```
preg_match_all('#([^\n]*)#', '中文', $t_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($t_matches);
```

I know how to correctly match Chinese character from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923319/php-check-if-the-string-has-chinese-chars). I am just wondering why the `[\P{C}]*` failed.

Comment: Flags: `'#([\P{C}]*)#u'`

Comment: When you deal with Unicode strings, use the [UNICODE modifier](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/5138/regex-modifiers-flags/18161/unicode-modifier).

Comment: Shouldn't it be the lower-case `p` ?

Comment: @CD001: No, because the `\P{C}` matches any char but a control char. `\p{C}` won't match any letters, it only matches control chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah - gotcha, I was thinking of something like `\p{L}` where you're matching any unicode letter rather than *not* matching control characters :)

Comment: Thank you for all the help and the reference! I learned and added the UNICODE modifier `u` in the pattern and the problem is solved.