# PHP: make a string clickable

Tags: php, regex, string, eregi, ereg

For a Mandarin learning-tool I would like to create links for each chinese "character" within a word. For example I have the chinese word "自行车" (bicycle). Then I would like to make each of the three characters "clickable".

```php
$word = '自行车';
```

And the output should be:

```
$output = "<a href='?char=自'>自</a> 
<a href='?char=行'>行</a> 
<a href='?char=车'>车</a>";
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this regex you can split your characters.

```
preg_split('//u', "自行车", null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

the result is array of three character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace` to replace the chinese char with regular expression `/(\p{Han})/u` then replace it with what your need.

```
preg_replace("/(\p{Han})/u","<a href='?char=$1'>$1</a>",'ss自行车ss');
```

output:

```
ss<a href='?char=自'>自</a><a href='?char=行'>行</a><a href='?char=车'>车</a>ss
```

---

**Refer to** [Php - regular expression to check if the string has chinese chars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4923319/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract chars in a for loop and generate anchor tags.

```
<a href='<link?char=<extracted char>'><extracted char></a>
```